# yii2 - mPDF: Text rotation in a cell

Tags: yii2, mpdf

I am using **mPDF** in a **Yii2** project. 
I want to create a pdf with a table in it. Some of the **cells** in that table should have the **text rotated by 90 or 270 degrees**. 
Can anybody give me a hint? There is no related mPDF function as far as I know.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

As hinted in [this mPDF github issue](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/379), you can use `<tr text-rotate="45">` proprietary attribute. `rotate` CSS property could also work.

See the manual at https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html